# how to apply linear-gradient on html progress tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply the linear-gradient property to html progress bar tag.
This is how the visual would look like

[image]

Here's the jsfiddle for progress tag

https://jsfiddle.net/nick1111/3bLgLr9h/6/

```
<div><progress max="100" value="85" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="75" tabindex="-1 ></progress></div>

.horizontal-gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, blue, white);
}
```

I tried creating a css class for gradient but not sure how to apply it on progress bar tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to target `:progress-bar` and `:progress-value`. Something like this:

```css
progress {
  border: 0;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(33, 177, 89, .1), rgba(33, 177, 89, 1));
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(33, 177, 89, .1), rgba(33, 177, 89, 1));
}
```

```html
<div><progress color="#8ccc62" max="100" value="85" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="75" tabindex="-1"></progress></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @sol for the answer.

Comment: is it possible to apply linear-gradient on the color that user passes as an input. But then we cant create classes for all colors since user can pass any color. In my css i have background-color: currentColor; but i dont understand how to use currentColor with linear-gradient. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As you see in the style code, you have to use ::-webkit-progress-value for the value background, and ::-webkit-progress-bar for the background of the progress tag

```
progress {  
    /* Important Thing */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background: lightgray;
}
progress[value="65"]::-webkit-progress-value{

background: #dafcd6; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #dafcd6 0%, #57c64f 65%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #dafcd6 0%,#57c64f 65%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #dafcd6 0%,#57c64f 65%);

}
```